# Two healthy recovery partitions, why?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu, then removed it by deleting it's partitions, now I'm not sure why I have two recovery partitions and if one even belongs to Ubuntu or both are for my Windows OS

There is apparently no labelling:

[image: Windows partition]

I can't delete either, I'm not sure if I need both and if I don't which one do I force delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, it's generally not a good idea to try to destroy things you haven't identified yet.

Many Windows OEMs ship their machines with two recovery partitions, one small, one large. I have a configuration similar to yours. If you want to be sure they're Windows partitions, you can use `mountvol`:

1. Open an administrative command prompt.
2. Type `mountvol`. At the bottom of the output, there is a list of partitions and whether they have letters (mount points).
3. Choose a partition that has no mount points. Use the Command Prompts "Mark" feature (under Edit when you right-click) to copy its full name, the stuff that starts with `\\?\` and ends with `}\`.
4. Type `mountvol x:` (or whatever drive letter you want to give it) and then paste the volume's name after it. Press Enter. The volume takes on the drive letter you specified.
5. Change to that drive letter and do a `dir`, or check it out with Windows Explorer. If you can open it, it's a Windows-compatible file system and therefore almost certainly a Windows-created partition.
6. Back in the command prompt, type `mountvol x: /p`, again with `x:` as your preferred scratch drive letter, to remove the mount.
7. Repeat steps 3 through 6 for all mysterious drives.

I am, however, fairly certain you will find that they are all Windows partitions.